# Remove '/' from href target id element in the url

Tags: html, anchor

When the an anchor link is clicked which is targeted to an `#id` element, the `#id` is added current URL with a `/` after the `#` symbol. Because of this, the back button of the browser needs to be clicked twice to navigate to the previous page. How to fix this.

Example:

**Current Page URL:** `http://localhost/about`

```
<a href="#message">Click Here</a>

<div id="#message">My message</div>
```

**Curent Page Url after 'Click Here' link is clicked** `http://localhost/about#/message`

**#/message** - The `/` after the `#` symbol in the URL is causing the problem.

Is there any way to completely remove #id from adding to the URL when the link is clicked?

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way. The url will have to look like `http://localhost/about#message`

Comment: @AmitJoki is right. That is not the default behavior of an anchor link. Also, you have a mistake in your html - instead of closing it with an `</a>` you're closing it with `</href>`

Comment: @AmitJoki i have edited my question. It is </a> link. when i hover the mouse the tooltip shows the correct url but in url the '/' is adding.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#message">Click Here</a>

<div id="#message">My message</div>
```

Bad closing tags lead to badly rendered html